# Understanding of Android Log files

Tags: android

I have Log.d to log some info inside the the source files.

1)Where do you see the output of that Log.d statement?  Logcat has way too many process and kernel operations listed just junked up the whole place. I don't need to know all those internal system operations. I only need to list the Log.d statement.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050601/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-log-messages-from-our-own-application-in-android/7050610#7050610

Comment: I followed that and added a filter, filter name, log tag and log level whick is debug. I reran the simulation, but console under the new filter is empty!. Nothing there.

Comment: If you are using the ddms standalone app: Did you mark the device that you want to watch (just click on it in the list on the top left)?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a filter as described in the 'adb logcat' help output. But you need to also silence the things you are not interested in. For instance, if you specified the Tag as 'MyApp' you can just have logcat dump the MyApp lines using:
 adb logcat 'MyApp:v,*:s' which silences everything (*:s) and displays anything tagged with 'MyApp' that is verbose and above. For debug and above use 'MyApp:d' instead.

Comment: This is manual way of setting the tag right?  for graphical way, it should be simpler? I mean , you don't have set those tag on each line.

Comment: Yes - this describes using logcat filtering from the command-line.