# How to filter out a tagname in Eclipse LogCat viewer

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I have an Android application that "spams" the LogCat and I would like to remove its logcat entries in order to have an output more readable.

Is it possible to have a filter that remove the LogCat entries for a specific tag name? Or a search pattern that does the trick?

Comment: @pankaj It is not exactly what I want. I want a way to remove some specific entries rather than isolate them.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Yes. Create a filter where the "By log tag" field is

```
^(?!.*(MYTAG)).*$
```

where `MYTAG` is the tag you don't want to see. I am not a regexp expert (a "regexpert"? ;-) ) so there may be a simpler way to do that negation, but I just tried that and it works.

You can play around with the filter in the field just above the Log Cat message area, by entering filter strings there, like this:

```
tag:^(?!.*(DeskClock|dalvik|wpa)).*$
```

which will show all messages *except* tags "DeskClock", "dalvik", and "wpa".

Comment: You can also add this regex to the search bar above the listing in the Eclipse LogCat View.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I've always had problems building regexp that would show only the output that doesn't match. Very helpful. DDMS is actually useful now.

Comment: Can someone please explain how this expression exactly works?

Comment: You can fit as many tags as you want into this expression by changing it to the following form: `^(?!.*(tag1|tag2|tag3|...|tagn)).*$`

Answer (score 9):

This might not seem directly relevant to the question but here is a regex which filters out most of the system generated logs when you put this in your tag filter [as described by Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140642/847575).

```
^(?!(WifiMulticast|WifiHW|MtpService|PushClient|InputMethodManager|Provider|SurfaceTextureClient|ImageLoader|dalvikvm|OpenGLRenderer|skia|AbsListView|MediaPlayer|AudioManager|VelocityTracker|Drv|Jpeg|CdpDrv|IspDrv|TpipeDrv|iio|ImgScaler|IMG_MMU|ResMgrDrv|JpgDecComp|JpgDecPipe|mHalJpgDec|PipeMgrDrv|mHalJpgParser|jdwp|libEGL|Zygote|Trace|InputEventReceiver|SpannableStringBuilder|IInputConnectionWrapper|MotionRecognitionManager|Choreographer|v_galz|SensorManager|Sensors|GC|LockPatternUtils|SignalStrength|STATUSBAR-BatteryController|BatteryService|STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar|WifiP2pStateTracker|Watchdog|AlarmManager|BatteryStatsImpl|STATUSBAR-Clock))
```

I keep updating this list of tags as i encounter them testing on different devices. The list is not exhaustive and you are free to contribute to this answer. I am sure this will save an hour for many.

If there are other other logs you need filtered out, append them to this regex using a ' | ' character.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on which way you view your logcat.

If you are using the GUI logcat interface it's best to create a filter for the tags you want to see. These get dropped into a seperate category. Though the ui changed a bit you can use this [old answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050601/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-log-messages-from-our-own-application-in-android/7050610#7050610). Should be clear how this is used *(make sure that the "display saved filters tab" button is pressed though, otherwise you won't see the "Add filter" button. You can find that on the top-right of the log)*. I'm not aware of any option that lets you filter out certain tags from the whole logstream.

If you are using the command line you can mute certain tags. Example:

```
adb logcat AndroidRuntime:S *:V
```

shows everything (`*:V`) up to the verbose log level, except the tag *AndroidRuntime*, which will be limited to the "silence" loglevel, which means it will print nothing.

To display a single tag you can use

```
adb logcat *:S MyAppTag:V OtherTag:V
```

Same way, everything gets silenced except *MyAppTag* and *OtherTag*. See [Filtering Log Output](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, `adb logcat <tag-name>:S *:V` is what I was looking for. I would like the same behavior in the Eclipse GUI logcat interface, but for now I will use the command line.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get chosen solution to work properly in Android Studio (the IDE that will come with future versions of android SDK). However the following regex solved my problem:

```
^(?!dalvikvm)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a trick:

```
 Log.d(TAG, "MyTag" + message);
```

As you can see, when I filter with a key "MyTag", it only shows log from my tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response, but maybe useful.
In the Eclipse environment, in the LogCat view, above the table there is a search box.
Pay attention, when empty it reads:

> Search for messages. Accepts Java regexes. Prefix with pid:, app:,
>   tag: or text: to limit scope.

It means you can filter your tag by writing there **tag:MyTag** or even regex **tag:My.***

Answer (score -1):

Another way to filter out log messages that don't originate from YOUR app is to select:

Log Level: Verbose

"Show only selected application" (from the filter selection drop down)

Then select your application from the from the drop down debuggable list in the logcat window.

This should only show log messages and output from your app.

Comment: Anyway.... you need regex to filter out unwanted texture elaboration... and  others stuff with your app name.