# "Doing SSL_Read()" in LogCat

Tags: android

I'm getting a ton, like hundreds at a time, of these messages in LogCat:

```
07-15 21:24:48.096: D/NativeCrypto(1606): Doing SSL_Read()
07-15 21:24:48.096: D/NativeCrypto(1606): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0
```

Can anyone tell me what they are and if there is a way to not get them? I know I can filter them out but they are filling up my log so much that I'm not getting anything else.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply "exclusive" filter on the logcat output like this:

```
tag:^(?!(NativeCrypto))
```

This will get rid of `NativeCrypto` and `NativeCrypto-jni`.

Or if you want several words to exclude, try

```
tag:^(?!(NativeCrypto|System|SomethingElse))
```

Good luck!

EDIT: 
You may also want to check out this SO post [How to filter out a tagname in Eclipse LogCat viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889888/how-to-filter-out-a-tagname-in-eclipse-logcat-viewer)

Answer (score 0):

Try actually filtering for a specific log tag.

Comment: The log tag for the SSL_Read() messages is the same for my app so filtering doesn't help. I'm really curious as to what the messages actually mean and if it's a sign of me doing something bad in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to pipe logcat through grep.

It seems that all Android 4.x devices suffer from massive logcat spam at the DEBUG level.  I'm not sure if this is Google's doing or the vendors', but all the ones I've worked with spam this NativeCrypto garbage.  IMO, the OS should use VERBOSE and leave the DEBUG level for apps.