# Android options menu item failing when clicked?

Tags: android, menu, start-activity

I am trying to add an options menu to my Android project. The option menu displays just fine, but when the only option is clicked it fails. Debugging hasn't helped me (I haven't been developing android very long).

The XML that draws the menu item is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_server"
          android:icon="@drawable/plus"
          android:title="@string/add_server"
          android:showAsAction="never"
          />

</menu>
```

The code that calls the method when said option is clicked is:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_server:
                    addNewServer();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

The method is:

```
public void addNewServer() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(AndNetQCheckDemo.this, AddServer.class);
 AndNetQCheckDemo.this.startActivity(intent);       
}
```

When I click the button, it highlights and then fails. The debugger makes it to the `.this.startActivity` line then fails with an instrumentation error which I don't understand.

The device I'm using is a Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.0.4.

Comment: might be helpful to post the logcat with the error code

Comment: See if you have the `AddServer` activity added to the manifest.

Comment: @Anthea is there a code I should be looking out for? The LogCat appears to be going mad, constantly updating.

Comment: in ecplipse there is a pause button on the right upper side to stop the logcat from updating - you are searching for a big red text. In the column tag you should find your application name. Otherwise it is also possible to apply a filter on the log. See that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889888/how-to-filter-out-a-tagname-in-eclipse-logcat-viewer

Comment: @Luksprog yes, you were correct, I always miss this and it's so simple. However, with that problem solved I now have another. The AddServer page doesn't show. Code edited into my original post

Comment: Solved

Essentially me being a newbie.

First issue correctly answered by @Luksprog

Second issue was a simple id miss match.

Apologies

Comment: I appreciate this is an old question, but it appears to be two questions in one, and we're very keen that questions are posted separately here. I will roll it back to the one-question state, and if an answer can be posted (if you think that will help a future reader) that would be great. (It sounds like the second issue is not worth saving for posterity anyway).