# Remove admob log in logcat

Tags: android, logging, admob

Is there a way to stop Admob from outputting a log into the logcat? I was looking around and the answers that iwas given were for programs that are about to be released. I just find that it clogs up my logcat, especially if i am debugging other stuff and they get lost in the logs due to Admob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question [How to filter out a tagname in Eclipse LogCat viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889888/how-to-filter-out-a-tagname-in-eclipse-logcat-viewer)

They propose to filter LogCat view by something like

```
tag:^(?!.*(AdMob)).*$
```

I never tried that myself.

Comment: I thinks it's now "Ads" not Admob