# Samsung Phones emit a lot of log messages on logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat

Logcat on Samsung phones is a real pain. They have just too much on the logcat of their own to make our developing life easy. Is there a way to reduce and filter **OUT** their message for noisy packages on logcat ?

I am not asking if there is a way to filter what I want to see, I need to filter **OUT** what I dont want to see.

Comment: This problem occurs for me too. This is very annoying, lots of process occurs in background and all the logs are shown in red color as if our application has thrown an error.

Comment: Below link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889888/how-to-filter-out-a-tagname-in-eclipse-logcat-viewer

Comment: nexus is probably the best device for android development just because it does not spit ton of log. when i use a samsung device, i cannot work :(

Comment: Samsung developers should probably understand the difference between release and debug builds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reject out what you don't want to see like this, add a new filter and put this in the "By tag name" field. You can of course know the tag you want to reject from the LogCat itself.

```
^(?!.*(UNWANTEDTAG)).*$
```

This is an example of one I use:

```
^(?!.*(SignalStrength|StatusBar|TelephonyManager|Wifi|SignalClusterView)).*$
```

I now don't see any messages from those tags

Edit 1:
and this is a very long one from my library :D , you would barely see something there:

```
^(?!(WifiMulticast|WifiHW|MtpService|PushClient|Tethering|SensorService|WifiStateMachine|hawaii.hwcomposer|AnyDo|PowerManagerService|Monitor|IconMerger|InputMethodManager|SignalClusterView_dual|StatusBar.NetworkController_dual|LocationManagerService|Provider|SurfaceTextureClient|ImageLoader|dalvikvm|OpenGLRenderer|skia|AbsListView|MediaPlayer|AudioManager|VelocityTracker|Drv|Jpeg|CdpDrv|IspDrv|TpipeDrv|iio|ImgScaler|IMG_MMU|ResMgrDrv|JpgDecComp|JpgDecPipe|mHalJpgDec|PipeMgstatrDrv|mHalJpgParser|jdwp|libEGL|Zygote|Trace|InputEventReceiver|SpannableStringBuilder|IInputConnectionWrapper|MotionRecognitionManager|Choreographer|v_galz|SensorManager|Sensors|GC|LockPatternUtils|STATUSBAR*|SignalStrength|STATUSBAR-BatteryController|BatteryService|STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar|WifiP2pStateTracker|Watchdog|AlarmManager|BatteryStatsImpl|STATUSBAR-Clock)).*$
```

Comment: Thank for this, it's been driving me crazy ! It works but your extended example hides everything, even the current app. How so ? What can I remove from your "Edit1" to remove the noise but keep my app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the option "Show only selected application", localized on the top right corner of the LogCat window.
[View an illustration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkihm.png)