# LogCat in Eclipse Android Debugging Exclusion Tag

Tags: eclipse, android-logcat

How do I create an exclusion tag in eclipse. I want all tags beginning with Media to be omitted from LogCat in Eclipse. Because my program has a lot of different tags but everything beginning with media I want to go away. I can only tell it specifically what I want to see but there seems to be no way to tell it what I do not want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a related to [How to filter out a tagname in Eclipse LogCat viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889888/how-to-filter-out-a-tagname-in-eclipse-logcat-viewer).

In general, you want to use Java regular expressions to filter out/select some particular log lines. 
Example: `^(?!(media)).*$`

Comment: Explain to me what each symbol means please. I didn't know this would work in Eclipse like that, I thought it was only for ADB.

Comment: `^` means the beginning of the line
`(?!pattern)` is called a negative lookahead and is used to exclude a pattern
`.*` means any character, repeated 0 or more times
`$` is for the end of the line